# Session Cache Limiter

Tags: php, session, warnings

Yes I know this has already been done, but this problem is different.

The error I get is:

```
Warning: session_start(): Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at /home/u5558315/public_html/admin/index.php:1) in /home/u5558315/public_html/admin/includes/php/header.php on line 3
```

I've looked if there is white space in front and behind the PHP start tag, end tag and anything before the actual `session_start()`.

`session_start();` is the first thing on the PHP script after the actual `<?php` tag.
I've also tried `ob_start()` but also fails to fix the error.

***header.php***

```
<?php
ob_start();
session_start();
include('includes/php/functions.php');
if (!isset($_SESSION['login'])) {
redirect('login.php');
}
$now = time(); // checking the time now when home page starts 
if($now > $_SESSION['expire']){
echo '<script type="javascript">
alert("Your Session Has Timedout");
</script>';
session_destroy();
}
ob_end_flush();
?>
```

***index.php***

```
<?php
include('includes/php/header.php');
?>
```

All things suggested by other StackOverflow questions have failed to work.
Is there anything else that I could do to fix the issue?

Regards,
Tim Vos

Comment: output in `functions.php` ?

Comment: Try to add `var_dump(ob_get_contents());` before the session start. There must be something in the buffer. You could just do a `ob_clean()` to fix some whitespaces being printed before, but you should really find the issue in your scripts.

Comment: I just checked, it has nothing to do with the error and it also has no errors

Comment: It returns, `bool(false)` and `ob_clean()` also has no effect.

Comment: There must be some spaces or newlines before `<?php` in index.php!

Comment: That does work either.

Answer (score 0):

What does the redirect function do?

Error shows something on line 5. So its something with redirect function.

I think this should solve your problem.

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['login'])) {
    header('location:login.php');
    exit;
}
```

Comment: There should be absolute path after `Location:` header, read here: http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html

Comment: That was my fault. I had tried to put the session after the include but also failed. But that was the error when it was still there. Let me update the error. The redirect function is another way of redirection that doesn't use `header(Location: )`.

Answer (score 0):

I honestly don't know how I fixed it or even if I fixed it, but it works.

The host might of changed something in the config to fix it, but I honestly don't know.

Thanks for the answers